# Stick XIB to Navigation Bar ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have xib and I registered it:

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCollectionView" bundle:nil] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionView"];
```

and I'd like to stick it to navigation bar - every time it must be under navigation bar (f.e. when I scroll my page). How to pin (stick) it to navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your flow layout files init you can use:

```
self.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

if you don't have custom layout file in the `viewDidLoad` use:

```
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout // casting is required as its feature of UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

Objective C version

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*) collection.collectionViewLayout;
layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = YES;
```